# Passing complex objects in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to pass complex object from my view to my controller.

I give the ability to the client to create infinity listBox.

How can I transfer this to the controller?

Here is description:
For every `CompanyFeedbackTopic`, the client can insert infinite `CompanyFeedBackQuestion(Text with int)`.

I have this objects:

```
public class CompanyFeedbackTopic
    {
        /***fields***/
        private readonly int m_topicId;
        private int m_companyFeedbackId;   
        private int m_formatFeedbackId;    
        private int m_percent;
        private List<CompanyFeedbackQuestion> m_companyFeedbackQuestionList;

        /***constractors***/
        public CompanyFeedbackTopic(int topicId, int companyFeedbackId, int formatFeedbackId, int percent, 
                                    List<CompanyFeedbackQuestion> companyFeedbackQuestionList)
        {
            m_topicId = topicId;
            m_companyFeedbackId = companyFeedbackId;
            m_formatFeedbackId = formatFeedbackId;
            m_percent = percent;
            m_companyFeedbackQuestionList = companyFeedbackQuestionList;
        }

        /***get/set***/
        public int TopicId
        { get { return m_topicId; } }
        public int CompanyFeedbackId
        { get { return m_companyFeedbackId; } set { m_companyFeedbackId = value; }}
        public int FormatFeedbackId
        { get { return m_formatFeedbackId; } set { m_formatFeedbackId = value; }}
        public int Percent
        { get { return m_percent; }  set { m_percent = value; }}
        public List<CompanyFeedbackQuestion> CompanyFeedbackQuestionList
        { get { return m_companyFeedbackQuestionList; } set { m_companyFeedbackQuestionList = value; }
        }

        /***functions***/
    }


public class CompanyFeedbackQuestion
    {
        /***fields***/
        private readonly int m_questionId;
        private int m_topicId;
        private string m_question;
        private int m_fieldGradeOptions;

        /***constractors***/
        public CompanyFeedbackQuestion(int questionId, int topicId, string question, int fieldGradeOptions)
        {
            m_questionId = questionId;
            m_topicId = topicId;
            m_question = question;
            m_fieldGradeOptions = fieldGradeOptions;            
        }

        /***get/set***/
        public int QuestionId
        { get { return m_questionId; } }
        public int TopicId
        { get { return m_topicId; } set { m_topicId = value; }}
        public string Question
        {  get { return m_question; } set { m_question = value; } }
        public int FieldGradeOptions
        { get { return m_fieldGradeOptions; } set { m_fieldGradeOptions = value; }}   
    }
```

And this is the view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitNewForm", "ManageFeedback", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.Label("Choose feedback type: ")
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedFeedbaclType, Model.FeedbackTypesDic.Select(i => new SelectListItem() { Text = i.Value, Value = i.Key.ToString() }), "---")

    <div id="formTable">
        @foreach (var item in Model.FormatFeedbackDic)
        {
            <h4>@item.Value</h4>
            <table id="@item.Key">
                <tr>
                    <td class="tableHeader">#</td>
                    <td class="tableHeader">question</td>
                    <td class="tableHeader">Grade Options</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBox("SS", "", new { style = "width:500px" })</td>
                    <td>@Html.DropDownList("fieldGradeOptions", Model.GetDropDownList()) </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br />
            <button onclick="AddNewRow(@item.Key);">+</button>
            <hr />
        }
    </div>
    <br />
    <button onclick="SubmitForm();">Create new feedback</button>
}
```

How can I transfer it to the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do two things

1. Replace all the foreach loops with simple for loops. Example -

   for(int i = o; i< Model.FormatFeedbackDic.Count; i++){}

2.Replace this line //button onclick="SubmitForm();">Create new feedback// with

/input type = "sumbit" />

Now it will pass the complex model back to controller